# A granted authority textual representation is required in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problem with registration permissions in Spring Security 
I can't do the methods register

I tried to set access to each path but it didn't help

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
        public Long register(@RequestBody User user){
        return userService.register(user);
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll();
    }
}
```

**UserSerice**

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    public Long register(User user){
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user.getId();
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String role;       

    public User() {
    }

   ..get and set...

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> listRole = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        listRole.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        return listRole;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A granted authority textual
>   representation is required    at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:284)
>   ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority.(SimpleGrantedAuthority.java:38)
>   ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]   at
>   com.xxx.xx.models.User.getAuthorities(User.java:71) ~[classes/:na]    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your User model class, make sure that a role is set, for your getAuthorities() method to work.

The error you are getting hints to the fact that you are doing a "new SimpleGrantedAuthority" with a "null" role.

```
 @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> listRole = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        listRole.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role)); // this is the problematic line!
        return listRole;
    }
```

If you don't have a role, then simply return an empty list instead.

```
 @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
         return Collections.emptyList();
    }
```

Comment: I get this: at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 5] (through reference chain: models.User["authorities"]->java.util.Collections$EmptyList[0])] with root cause
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException:

Comment: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 5] (through reference chain: models.User["authorities"]->java.util.Collections$EmptyList[0])

Answer (score 0):

This is my JSON and I use defult ROLE. 
I try return an empty list but I have this same  error

```
{
  "accountNonExpired": true,
  "accountNonLocked": true,
  "authorities": [
    {
      "authority": "string"
    }
  ],
  "credentialsNonExpired": true,
  "enabled": true,
  "id": 0,
  "lastName": "Piotr",
  "name": "Piotr",
  "password": "Piotr",
  "role": "ROLE_ADMIN",
  "username": "Piotr"
}
```

Error form POSTMAN

```
**"timestamp": "2020-04-01T15:20:05.670+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "JSON conversion problem: A granted authority textual representation is required; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: A granted authority textual representation is required\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.xxx`enter code here`.xxx.models.User[\"authorities\"])",
    "path": "/register"
}**
```

Comment: see my updated answer. with an emptylist it should definitely work, because you are not crating new SimpleGrantedAuthorities anymore and that's where you get your error. maybe the error is different then?

Comment: I found the error is JSON's fault because I use swagger and he generates me a bad Json

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to create user object like

**new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.Usersername,passwordEncoder.encode user.getPass ()), grantedAuthorityList);**

this work form me!

```
@Service  
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
YourRepository yourRepository;


@Autowired
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityList = new ArrayList<>();
    User user = yourRepository.findUserByUser(username);

    List<String> listRoles = new ArrayList<>();
    //List<UserRoles> userRoles = user.getUserRoleList();

    user.getUserRoleList().forEach(role->listRoles.add(role.getRole().getRole()));// get role from database - usa il tuo modo **

    grantedAuthorityList = listRoles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());


    //*** important ****
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username,
            passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPass()), grantedAuthorityList);


}
```